# How to write a nodeJs function to make request through superagent with (async+forloop+timeInterval)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, settimeout

I'm trying to get response from my api with some interval for log purpose. I have tried some code with superagent - async function. It's not working properly can anyone help me with this ?

```
    for (var i = x; i <= xy; i++) {
    (async function(){
    const url = String("myApiUrl");
        const response = await superagent.get(url);
        fs.appendFile("test.txt", "\n"+response, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });
    })();    
}
```

Comment: Put the Async IIFE outside of the loop.

Comment: Where's the interval? What is `xy`?

Comment: @Bergi it's a param of url, its integer

Comment: I wanna make request to server with interval, inside iteration. @jonas can you explain please?